# What is the best way to host images in an Angular app

Tags: angular, web

I have a small blog, written with Angular (v2+) where in each post I display a bunch of pictures. I currently serve the pictures with my static files from my assets folder. Although I try compressing and resizing the images, in order to keep at least OK quality it still sums up to several MBs per post, which I think creates a huge overhead on the site's loading time.

I wonder if there is a better way to host the images on a third party storage site and just set a link as src in the image tag.

I tried using Flickr but it is kind of a mess, so does google photos. I just want to get a simple web address per picture.

Any ideas?

Comment: try spaces from digitalocean, they are free for first 2 months and then after $5/mo